# Fires logout button when I press enter key on IE

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net master page with a logout button. Also I have 20 web Form use this master page.

My issues is when I press enter key on the page even if the logout button in not focused, the logout button gets fired.
This issues is happening only in IE browser.

I want to prevent the firing logout button if the logout button is not focused

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnLogout" runat="server"  useSubmitBehavior="false"
                                    ImageUrl="~/Images/logout_img.jpg" Width="33px" Height="35px" onclick="imgbtnLogout_Click" />  

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
       
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>
</body>
```

Can any one help me to fix this issue

Comment: [Why are Enter Keypresses Clicking My Buttons in IE?](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/05/22/why-are-enter-keypresses-clicking-my-buttons-in-ie/) - "All `<input>`s should be within a `<form>`, and all forms should have a submit button. If for whatever reason that’s not an option, you can add `type="button"` to the `<button>` This will override the default `type="submit"` and prevent IE from clicking the `<button>` on Enter keypresses."

Comment: Post the markup for your master page where the logout button is

Comment: @ Denis Wessels, I have added the master page code

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue, which is resolved by implementing below code.

step1: add button control in your master page.

step 2: set default button in form tag in your master page.

Step 3: Run your application and check your issue now.